# Хостинг wcf служб на домашнем пк

Tags: c#, администрирование, wcf

пробую сделать простенький чатик на c# wcf

Нашел пример для работы на одном пк,([вот видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QohqDyTjclw)), но хочу заставить работать клиент на любом пк, в том числе и в других сетях, по сему немного сменил код

Белый ip в наличии, порты 745, 766(см. код) и 80 на роутере и брандмауэре открыл, но при добавлении ссылки на службу в проекте клиента происходит таймаут(хост в это время работал, как в [примере](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QohqDyTjclw))
[image: вот ошибка]

строго прошу не судить, я только начал изучение темы, просто хочу сразу пробовать результат, а не сидеть на одном пк с несколькими клиентами, скучно ведь

вот весь код службы:

IChatService.cs

```
namespace RealChat
{

[ServiceContract]
public interface IChatService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Connect(string name);

    [OperationContract]
    void Disconnect(int id);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void sendMessage(string msg, int id);
}

public interface IChatServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void messageCallback(string msg);
}
}
```

ChatService.cs

```
namespace RealChat
{

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ChatService : IChatService
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    static int counter = 1;

    public int Connect(string name)
    {
        var user = new User()
        {
            ID = counter,
            Name = name,
            Context = OperationContext.Current
        };

        sendMessage(name + "підключився", 0);
        users.Add(user);
        counter++;
        return user.ID;
    }



    public void Disconnect(int id)
    {
        if (users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == id) != null)
        {
            sendMessage(users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == id).Name + "відключився", 0);
            users.Remove(users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == id));
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(string msg, int id)
    {
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            string answer = "(";
            if (users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == id) != null)
            {
                answer += DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                answer += ") ";
                answer += users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == id).Name;
                answer += " : ";
                answer += msg;
                answer += "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                answer += DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                answer += ") ";
                answer += "SERVER";
                answer += " : ";
                answer += msg;
                answer += "\n";
            }

            user.Context.GetCallbackChannel<IChatServiceCallback>().messageCallback(answer);
        }
    }
}
}
```

app.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="RealChat.ChatService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="RealChat.IChatService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RealChat/ChatService/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Вот хост:

Program.cs

```
namespace RealChatHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RealChat.ChatService)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("started");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBeh">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="RealChat.ChatService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBeh">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="RealChat.IChatService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://77.120.92.132:745" />
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://77.120.92.132:746"/>


        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

А вот как было при попытке коннекта по локалке

```
         <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.5:745" />
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://192.168.1.5:746"/>
```

Dhcp настроен

Прошу указать мне на мои ошибки
заранее благодарен

Comment: Port forwarding на роутера настроен?

Comment: Вопрос делится на две части. Работает ли в локалке с соседнего компа, когда заработает можете настраивать ваш роутер чтобы работало в сети интернет. И если первая ещё хоть как-то относится к WCF (проверить, что адрес который слушает сервер совпадает с точкой куда ломится клиент), то вторая даже к программированию не относится, не то, что c# - чистое администрирование.

Comment: по локалке не работает

Comment: Port forwarding это перенаправление портов на пк?

Comment: (порты проброшены, если что)

Answer (score 0):

помогло отключение фаервола и вот такое в App.config:

```
 <add baseAddress="http://77.120.92.132:745" />
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:746"/>
```